# Splitting very large string separated with comma and i need to split 50 items only per row

Tags: excel, vba

im having very big string on 1st row.so 1st row contains lots of items with comma like below

12345,54322,44444,222222222,444444,121,333,44444,........

I just need to split this till 50 items in every row. lets assume there are 700 items separated with comma and I want to keep till 50 items only in 1st row and then next 50 in 2nd row and so on.

I tried with the below code which splits till 50 for sure but im not sure if this will works going forward. so need help on this

```
OutData = Split(InpData, ",")(50)
MsgBox OutData
```

Comment: Can you show some sample output? How would your desired output look like?

Comment: suppose im having 1000 items in 1st row separated with commas. output should break this 1000 into 50 at first row, 2nd 50 items in next row and next 50 items in 3rd row, so on.  example: lets take 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 these are 10 items in string and i want to be break it into 2 and keeping that 2 in 1 row.   [1st row: 1,2] [2nd row: 3,4] like that. but in my case it should break into 50

Comment: Right, so with the last example, the data in a single cell remains comma-seperated: `1,2`. And the data in the cell right below that would become `3,4` etc etc. Do you really want to use VBA though?

Comment: exactly. but in my case it should break 50 items, but not only 2items like 1,2

Comment: i want to use vba because the excel report which i got nearly 700 items in 1st row. so i need code to break into 50 items in each row till end of items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in many more ways, but one would be to replace every nth comma. For example through Regular Expressions:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11"
Dim n As Long: n = 2
Dim arr() As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "([^,]*(?:,[^,]*){" & n - 1 & "}),"
    arr = Split(.Replace(s, "$1|"), "|")
End With

End Sub
```

---

The pattern used means:

- `(` - Open 1st capture group;

  - `[^,]*` - Match 0+ (Greedy) characters other than comma;
  - `(?:` - Open a nested non-capture group;

    - `,[^,]*` - Match a comma and again 0+ characters other than comma;
    - `){1}` - Close the non-capture group and match n-1 times (1 time in the given example);
  - `),` - Close the capture group and match a literal comma.

Replace every match with the content of the 1st capture group and a character you know is not in the full string so we can split on that character. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/s9BtL2/1)

---

I suppose you can do whatever you like with the resulting array. You probably want to transpose it into the worksheet.

Comment: yeah I looped through the arr  and that will send result in each row based on the array  index. Thank you so much for the solution. its working like Flash and accurate too

Comment: @harshakazama, good to know it worked. Just know you can also transpose the array into the worksheet without any loop. Much faster.

Comment: Nice solution! Voted it up...